# context in componentDidMount appears as null

Tags: reactjs

I currently have a context provider.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.state.memberID === null) {
      try {
        this.checkAuthUser();
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    }
  }

checkAuthUser = () => {
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    this.props.firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
      if(authUser) {
        resolve(authUser);
      } else {
          reject(new Error("Not authorized"));
        }
      })
  })
  .then( authDetails => {
    this.props.firebase.getOrgID(authDetails.uid).on('value', snapshot => {
      const setSnapshot = snapshot.val();
      const getOrganizationID = Object.keys(setSnapshot)[0];
      this.setState({ memberID: authDetails.uid, orgID: getOrganizationID })
    })
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

When I try to use this in another component:

```
  static contextType = AuthDetailsContext;

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('here is context: ' + this.context.orgID);
    if(this.context.orgID) {
    this.setState({currentOrganization: this.context.orgID, loading: true}, () => {
      this.getMembersInDB('1');
    })
    }
  }
```

My console.log is null.  Means the context isn't registering yet.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are aware that unless you `await` your `checkAuthUser` function, your `catch` won't, well, catch?

Comment: Ah dumb me.  Await the second firebase call right?  @James

Comment: you really want to be awaiting both...

Comment: having just relooked at your firebase calls, you can't await them, they are events. My original comment was simply pointing out that the `try... catch` around your `checkAuth` call won't actually do anything because the Promise internally catches the error and logs it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design here seems flawed i.e. when your provider is mounted you send the API request and then when your descendant component is mounted you try to use it - these operations will happen in quick succession, far quicker than it would take for an API call to return from a server.

In your provider, if you *must* have a user before the component mounts then you need to delay rendering the child components until your API response completes i.e.

```
const AuthDetailsContext = React.createContext(null);

class AuthDetailsProvider extends PureComponent {
  ...
  componentDidMount() {  
    const { firebase } = this.props; 
    firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
      if (!authUser) {
        // Maybe set some other state state to inform the user?
        this.setState({ authError: new Error('Not Authorised') });
        return;
      }
      firebase.getOrgID(authUser.uid)
        .on('value', snapshot => {
          const setSnapshot = snapshot.val();
          const getOrganizationID = Object.keys(setSnapshot)[0];
          this.setState({ 
            authError: null,
            memberID: authUsermemberID.uid, 
            orgID: getOrganizationID 
          });
        });
    })
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.authError) return <b style={{ color: red }}>{this.state.error.message}</b>;
    if (!this.state.memberID) return <b>Authenticating...</b>

    return (
      <AuthDetailsContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        {this.props.children}
      </AuthDetailsContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```